# Timeout Error when publish the (Web API) Webservice

Tags: .net, web-services, settimeout, timeoutexception

I have a webservice written in **Web API** ,it uses some *very large tables* .

When I run it locally, through the code, it's Fine .But when I publish,and put it to the webserver , it (*SOMETIMES*) returns Error, most of the times, *Timeout Error* .

I set Timeout in web.Config with this line

```
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="1000" />
```

But before ending this time, Error happens.

I caught TimeoutError error using

```
 catch (TimeoutException e)
  {
     return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Timeout Error." + e.Message);
  }
```

But the error it gets is general ,

```
{ "Message": "An error has occurred." }
```

Its very likely to be timeout error, because when I test it with much less records , it works fine.

I'm new in Web API , also creating webservice . So What's my mistake in this?

Comment: Apply "Index" to your condition columns in your database.You can retrieve the data fast.

Comment: @Kakumanusivakrishna tnx for ure comment. but I think my problem is something byond database tunning, I've applied all required indexes , table partitionings , ... to DB. it works fine in my IIS (when I run from local system) , but it return timeout when it comes to webserver IIS7